# fetch all email from groups Facebook API

Tags: facebook

Show all group email those are attached with the groups

I have the below code please suggest

```
// get list of groups managed by user
    try {
        $requestGroups = $fb->get('/me/groups');
        $groups = $requestGroups->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($groups);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Getting respond as below you can see similarly i need email of added groups

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Java Developer
            [privacy] => OPEN
            [id] => xxxxxx
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => PHP Develop
            [privacy] => OPEN
            [id] => xxxxxx
        )

)
```

Comment: for now i am getting Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => xxxxx
            [privacy] => xxxxx
            [id] => xxxxxx
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => xxxxx
            [privacy] => OPEN
            [id] => xxxxx
        )

)

Answer (score 1):

Groups don´t have Emails. The only way to get any Email with the Graph API is by authorizing a User with the `email` permission and using the following endpoint: `/me?fields=email`